# How to get table after indexedDB was just openned via Dexie.js?

Tags: javascript, promise, indexeddb, dexie

I need to check if some table already exists into IndexedDB just after it was openned. But I don't know how to get DexieDB object inside 'then' statement.

```
this.db = new Dexie("DBNAME");
if (!this.db.isOpen()) {
    this.db.open().then(function () {
        //how to get this.db.table(storeName) here?
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

So `this.db` doesn't exist inside 'then' statement. How to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In Dexie

In Dexie in particular you don't have to call `isOpen` and `open()` like that, you can just `.open` and things will work like this:

```
// Declare db instance
var db = new Dexie("MyDatabase");

// Define Database Schema
//...
// Open Database
db.open(); 

db.trasnaction(...
```

#### In General

This is a classic JS context value. The way `this` works in JavaScript is different - [here is the canonical reference about it which you should read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1348195).

In addition - about passing parameters in then chains you should refer to [this excellent Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain) which covers the more general approach

The workarounds described there (with context) generally apply and contain more library specific code which could help you here.